# How can I persist an array to the database in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, arrays

I'm trying to persist an Array of Arrays to my SQLite database in Rails.

Right now, I've got an object that can hold such an Array, and instances appear to save with no problem. However, it's clearly not being persisted to the database-- when I call functions on My_Object.array in views different than the one that the array is created on, it comes out nil and doesn't work.

For example:

```
class My_Object < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :array
end
```

When I call `My_Object.new(:array => [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6] ])`, everything appears to work properly, but I can't access the `:array` property anywhere else, it just turns out nil.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First create a text column called `array` in your table. Then use [`serialize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Saving+arrays,+hashes,+and+other+non-mappable+objects+in+text+columns):

```
class My_Object < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :array
end
```

That will automatically serialize your array using YAML and automatically unpack it when you pull it back out of the database.

You should reconsider your design though. You won't be able to do anything at all with the serialized data inside the database and in particular, you won't be able to use it in queries. The YAML will be just an opaque blob that goes into the database and comes back out, the database won't be able to do anything else with it. If you're certain that the database will never need to look inside `array` then go ahead and use `serialize`, otherwise you'll want to set up extra tables to store your array data.

Comment: The actual application will be using this array almost exclusively... I'm just trying to implement conway's game of life into a rails app, using a `Game` object to hold the initial array-- This array is basically all that will be used in the entire application, as the whole point is to run it through the algorithm to get new points. Is this even possible using `serialize`? Should I just rework the entire program?

Comment: @Benjamin: `serialize` should be fine for something like that.

Comment: Just a minor point: You can use `serialize :array, Array` if you want to enforce an Array.

Comment: @Swanand: Thanks, that is worth mentioning.

Comment: Just to clarify, The fact that the `:array` object itself is made up of Arrays will have no effect here? I don't need to call `serialize` on each member of the parent Array, do I?

Comment: @Benjamin: Just `serialize :array` should be sufficient. You can say `serialize :array, Array` if you want to be explicit but I don't think there is a way to say "array or arrays" with `serialize`.