# Rails - how to model player abilities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making a text based game using RoR. However, I am unsure how to approach implementing different abilities the player has without creating a class or function for each different ability.

For instance, in Java I would most likely implement interfaces or abstract classes to deliver functionality without having to repeat the same code over and over again if it was an ability of a certain type (e.g. attack, buff, status effect, etc.)

While I have seen things on forcing Ruby/Rails to have abstract classes and such rather than do that I know that there must be some way to do this without forcing Ruby into a Java-like syntax.

The closest answer I have found on my own is using metaprogramming to essentially implement the builder design pattern, which would allow the code to build abilities on the fly from a list of values in the database.

Is there any easier way to generate abilities dynamically similar to something like Java or C#'s abstraction?

Comment: I think you should be able to do this with just Ruby on its own. I would research other text-based games built with Ruby and go from there.

Comment: I am using rails because I would like it to be web-based. However, I've been looking at implementing something close to what I'm familiar with in other languages. I hadn't thought of looking at other games written in Ruby. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to start is to take some of the many good rails tutorials.

Be patient, and learn the basics of and then you will be able to do your project.  Ruby on rails will be a great framework for your project

You will not need any meta programming.

Models, and in particular active record models, are classes that add standard capabilities making it easier to build complex sites.

Active record models also keep the data backed up in a database.

FYI I am assuming you want the game to work in the browser, and possibly be a multiplayer game.  Otherwise you don't really need rails, but I still recommend you use it.

Regarding abstract classes.  Don't worry about it.  You will declare your `Character` class, and give it methods modeling capabilities common to all player types.

You are also concerned with implementing 100's of classes.  What you need to distinguish is between state and behavior.  Many of your characters will have the same behavior just different initial states.  You only need to subclass to create special behaviors.

```
class Character
  DEFAULTS = {strength: 10, sex: :male} # etc
  def initialize(opts = {})
    opts = DEFAULTS.merge(opts)
    @strength = opts[:strength]
  end
  def strength
    # compute and return the strength common to all player types
    # for now:
    @strength
  end
  def wound(level)
    # update player state based on player getting wounded
    # for example:
    @strength = [0, @strength-level].max
  end

  # etc
end
```

Now you only need to subclass when the way a characters behavior is computed changes, otherwise the initializer will provide different character states.  For example the base class above can already produce an infinite variety of characters based just on strength and gender.

But say you have a Zombie character

```
class Zombie < Character
  def wound(level)
    super if level > 10
  end
end
```

Now the "behavior changes" so you will need to subclass and modify what happens when a zombie is wounded (nothing happens unless you really whack him.)

And as you can see the subclass need contain no more code than is needed to redefine the behavior needed.

All that Java's abstract class gives you in addition is way to "declare" other methods that the subclasses MUST implement.  You can do this in ruby by creating those methods in the parent class, and raising an error "Must Implement".

Comment: Exactly for the game, browser based multiplayer...

And I've been working through quite a few tutorials. I have learned quite a bit of the basics, but the way to implement a bunch of different abilities without having to code methods for each one is really tripping me up. Thanks for the advice though!

Comment: Thanks! The explanation really helped...I think I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

For the abilities of a player, one way to do it is to name them (e.g. use the names of the methods which implement the behavior), and store them in an array in your model, e.g. using `serialize`:
[How can I persist an array to the database in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998199/how-can-i-persist-an-array-to-the-database-in-ruby-on-rails)

For the administrative powers, I'd recommend to look on https://railscasts.com/ for some tutorials.

Search for `authorization`

The simplest way to do it is with the CanCan gem:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

Another gem for more elaborate authorization rules is Declarative Authorization: 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization

Comment: Thanks, I'm already using Devise for my login/authentication and coding my own authorization system. It seems fairly straightforward. 

As for the abilities, I guess I wasn't clear enough. I understand how to track/store the abilities the player has access too. The part that trips me up is if I have 100 different abilities how can I have them each potentially do different things without having to write 100 different classes?

Comment: It depends on what those abilities are - you could use `concerns` to add abilities to your models